# Query metadata for NTFS special files as unprivileged user?

Tags: c++, windows, ntfs

From an unprivileged user context, how can I query the size of the NTFS special files?

The size is the most important piece of metadata for me, but if I could get everything that is typically found in `WIN32_FIND_DATA` I would not mind it.

The NTFS special files I mean are (among others): `$Mft`, `$MftMirr`, `$LogFile`, `$BadClus` et cetera.

In order to open the MFT, I'd have to acquire certain privileges, open the volume and then parse the MFT. So that's out.

Also it seems to be impossible to open these files by name (for the majority of them), which precludes `NtQueryInformationFile()` and `GetFileInformationByHandle()`. Or maybe there is a combination of flags I haven't tried and it *is* possible to open them somehow for querying the file information?

Last but not least I don't get these files returned when using the respective Win32 APIs (`FindFirstFile()` et. al.), nor with `NtQueryDirectoryFile()` nor by using `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY` directly.

---

Yes, I understand that I can effectively get the size of the MFT using `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA`, but that's just one of these special files.

Comment: you can enumerate all ntfs files with all metadata (size, times, attributes, name) via `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD` even from guest. however - how task is set ? you have known hardcoded name, which you want query ? or simply enumerate all files or what ?

Comment: @RbMm: I only want to enumerate the few special NTFS files which I cannot enumerate any other way. I'll have a look at the FSCTL you mention, thanks. It may be suitable, especially since this part of the code is pretty much dependent on the file system of the directory/volume scanned. For the remainder of files I prefer to keep a file-system independent approach (at least for now) even if it takes a little longer to fully enumerate a volume this way. If you are certain this is a viable method, please write it up as an answer and I'll be sure to upvote it after verifying.

Comment: for *ntfs* enumerate files via `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD` will be much more faster compare `NtQueryDirectoryFile`. in many times faster. use `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` will be even more faster (compare `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD`) because you can got multiple file records in single call, but this not return size of file. for select best way need exactly understand - what you need and for what

Comment: As I wrote in my question already, my prime objective is to enumerate files and retrieve a given set of metadata (importantly size!). As for `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD` I'll have to put it to the test. `NtQueryDirectoryFile` internally uses `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY`, so it's perfectly reasonable to enumerate a whole bunch of entries at once by implementing the logic yourself. `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` is out for the reason you pointed out, it doesn't give me the metadata I need, even though it allows pretty much a documented method to read the MFT without _actually_ having to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on *ntfs* volume we can enumerate all file records with [`FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364568(v=vs.85).aspx). unfortunatelly format of [`FileRecordBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-ntfs_file_record_output_buffer) is undocumented/undeclared in windows headers. but this is common ntfs structs. buffer begin with `NTFS_RECORD_HEADER` (base class) after which will be several `NTFS_ATTRIBUTE` records. partial and custom definitions:

```
union NTFS_FILE_ID 
{
    LONGLONG IndexNumber;

    struct  
    {
        LONGLONG MftRecordIndex : 48;
        LONGLONG SequenceNumber : 16;
    };
};

struct NTFS_RECORD_HEADER 
{
    enum {
        FILE = 'ELIF',
        INDX = 'XDNI',
        BAAD = 'DAAB',
        HOLE = 'ELOH',
        CHKD = 'DKHC'
    } Type;
    USHORT UsaOffset;
    USHORT UsaCount;
    USN Usn;
};

struct NTFS_FILE_RECORD_HEADER : public NTFS_RECORD_HEADER
{
    USHORT SequenceNumber;
    USHORT LinkCount;
    USHORT AttributesOffset;
    USHORT Flags;
    ULONG BytesInUse;
    ULONG BytesAllocated;
    ULONGLONG BaseFileRecord;
    USHORT NextAttributeNumber;

    enum{
        flgInUse = 1, flgDirectory = 2
    };
};

struct NTFS_ATTRIBUTE 
{
    enum ATTRIBUTE_TYPE {
        StandardInformation = 0x10,
        AttributeList = 0x20,
        FileName = 0x30,
        ObjectId = 0x40,
        SecurityDescriptor = 0x50,
        VolumeName = 0x60,
        VolumeInformation = 0x70,
        Data = 0x80,
        IndexRoot = 0x90,
        IndexAllocation = 0xa0,
        Bitmap = 0xb0,
        ReparsePoint = 0xc0,
        EAInformation = 0xd0,
        EA = 0xe0,
        PropertySet = 0xf0,
        LoggedUtilityStream = 0x100,
        StopTag = MAXDWORD
    } Type;
    ULONG Length;
    BOOLEAN Nonresident;
    UCHAR NameLength;
    USHORT NameOffset;
    USHORT Flags;// 1 = Compresed
    USHORT AttributeNumber;
};

struct NTFS_RESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE : public NTFS_ATTRIBUTE 
{
    ULONG ValueLength;
    USHORT ValueOffset;
    USHORT Flags;
};

struct NTFS_NONRESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE : public NTFS_ATTRIBUTE 
{
    LONGLONG LowVcn;
    LONGLONG HighVcn;
    USHORT RunArrayOffset;
    UCHAR CompressionUnit;
    UCHAR Unknown[5];
    LONGLONG AllocationSize;
    LONGLONG DataSize;
    LONGLONG InitializedSize;
    LONGLONG CompressedSize;
};

struct NTFS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST
{
    NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE Type;
    USHORT Length;
    UCHAR NameLength;
    UCHAR NameOffset;
    LONGLONG LowVcn;
    LONGLONG FileReferenceNumber : 48;
    LONGLONG FileReferenceNumber2 : 16;
    USHORT AttributeNumber;
    USHORT Unknown[3];
};

struct NTFS_STANDARD_ATTRIBUTE 
{
    LONGLONG CreationTime;
    LONGLONG ChangeTime;
    LONGLONG LastWriteTime;
    LONGLONG LastAccessTime;
    ULONG FileAttributes;
    ULONG Unknown[3];
    ULONG QuotaId;
    ULONG SecurityId;
    ULONGLONG QuotaChange;
    USN Usn;
};

struct NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE
{
    NTFS_FILE_ID DirectoryId;
    LONGLONG CreationTime;
    LONGLONG ChangeTime;
    LONGLONG LastWriteTime;
    LONGLONG LastAccessTime;
    LONGLONG AllocationSize;
    LONGLONG DataSize;
    ULONG FileAttributes;
    ULONG EaSize;
    UCHAR FileNameLength;// in symbols !!
    UCHAR NameType;
    WCHAR FileName[];

    enum {
        systemName , longName, shortName, systemName2
    };
};
```

the code of enumeration all files can look like:

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

ULONG QFMD(PCWSTR szVolumeName)
{
    HANDLE hVolume = CreateFile(szVolumeName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

    if (hVolume == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG cb, BytesReturned;
    NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER nvdb;

    ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, 0, 0, &nvdb, sizeof(nvdb), &BytesReturned, 0));

    if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        NTFS_FILE_RECORD_INPUT_BUFFER nfrib;

        cb = FIELD_OFFSET(NTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER, FileRecordBuffer[nvdb.BytesPerFileRecordSegment]);

        PNTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER pnfrob = (PNTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER)alloca(cb);

        // search for maximum valid FileReferenceNumber
        LONG a = 0, b = MAXLONG, o;
        do 
        {
            nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart = o = (a + b) >> 1;

            err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD, 
                &nfrib, sizeof nfrib, pnfrob, cb, &BytesReturned, 0));

            err ? b = o : a = o + 1;

        } while(a < b);

        nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart--;

        DbgPrint("MftRecordCount=%u\n", nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.LowPart);


        union {
            PVOID FileRecordBuffer;
            PBYTE pb;
            NTFS_RECORD_HEADER* pnrh;
            NTFS_FILE_RECORD_HEADER* pnfrh;
            NTFS_ATTRIBUTE* pna;
            NTFS_RESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE* pnra;
            NTFS_NONRESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE* pnaa;
        };

        NTFS_FILE_ID nfi;
        UNICODE_STRING us = { sizeof (nfi), sizeof (nfi), (PWSTR)&nfi };
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), hVolume, &us };

        do 
        {
            FileRecordBuffer = pnfrob->FileRecordBuffer;

            if (err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD, 
                &nfrib, sizeof nfrib, pnfrob, cb, &BytesReturned, 0)))
            {
                break;
            }

            // are really file
            if (
                pnrh->Type != NTFS_RECORD_HEADER::FILE ||
                !(pnfrh->Flags & NTFS_FILE_RECORD_HEADER::flgInUse) ||
                pnfrh->BaseFileRecord
                )
            {
                continue;
            }

            ULONG FileAttributes = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES;
            ULONGLONG FileSize = 0;

            nfi.MftRecordIndex = pnfrob->FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart;
            nfi.SequenceNumber = pnfrh->SequenceNumber;

            pb += pnfrh->AttributesOffset;

            for( ; ; ) 
            {
                NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE* pnfa;
                NTFS_STANDARD_ATTRIBUTE* pnsa;

                switch (pna->Type)
                {
                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::StopTag:
                    goto __end;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::FileName:

                    pnfa = (NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE*)RtlOffsetToPointer(pnra, pnra->ValueOffset);

                    if (pnfa->NameType == NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE::longName)
                    {
                        //DbgPrint("<< %.*S\n", pnfa->FileNameLength, pnfa->FileName);
                    }
                    break;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::StandardInformation:

                    pnsa = (NTFS_STANDARD_ATTRIBUTE*)RtlOffsetToPointer(pnra, pnra->ValueOffset);
                    FileAttributes = pnsa->FileAttributes;
                    break;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::Data:
                    FileSize += pna->Nonresident ? pnaa->DataSize : pnra->ValueLength;
                    break;
                }

                pb += pna->Length;
            }

__end:;

            //HANDLE hFile;
            //IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

            //NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS,
            //  FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT| FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID | FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT);

            //if (0 <= status)
            //{
            //  NtClose(hFile);
            //}


        } while (0 <= (nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart = pnfrob->FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart - 1));

    }

    CloseHandle(hVolume);

    return err;
}
```

---

some [NTFS System Files](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-system-files.htm), but this list already old, exist more system files. if want concrete system file query need assign it number to `NTFS_FILE_RECORD_INPUT_BUFFER`. little changed code for query sys files only:

```
ULONG QFMD(PCWSTR szVolumeName)
{
    HANDLE hVolume = CreateFile(szVolumeName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

    if (hVolume == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG cb, BytesReturned;
    NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER nvdb;

    ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, 0, 0, &nvdb, sizeof(nvdb), &BytesReturned, 0));

    if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        NTFS_FILE_RECORD_INPUT_BUFFER nfrib;

        nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart = 0x30;

        cb = FIELD_OFFSET(NTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER, FileRecordBuffer[nvdb.BytesPerFileRecordSegment]);

        PNTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER pnfrob = (PNTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER)alloca(cb);

        union {
            PVOID FileRecordBuffer;
            PBYTE pb;
            NTFS_RECORD_HEADER* pnrh;
            NTFS_FILE_RECORD_HEADER* pnfrh;
            NTFS_ATTRIBUTE* pna;
            NTFS_RESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE* pnra;
            NTFS_NONRESIDENT_ATTRIBUTE* pnaa;
        };

        NTFS_FILE_ID nfi;
        UNICODE_STRING us = { sizeof (nfi), sizeof (nfi), (PWSTR)&nfi };
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), hVolume, &us };

        do 
        {
            FileRecordBuffer = pnfrob->FileRecordBuffer;

            if (err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD, 
                &nfrib, sizeof nfrib, pnfrob, cb, &BytesReturned, 0)))
            {
                break;
            }

            // are really file
            if (
                pnrh->Type != NTFS_RECORD_HEADER::FILE ||
                !(pnfrh->Flags & NTFS_FILE_RECORD_HEADER::flgInUse) ||
                pnfrh->BaseFileRecord
                )
            {
                continue;
            }

            ULONG FileAttributes = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES;
            ULONGLONG FileSize = 0;
            PCWSTR ShortName = 0, LongName = 0, SystemName = 0;
            UCHAR ShortNameLength = 0, LongNameLength = 0, SystemNameLength = 0;

            nfi.MftRecordIndex = pnfrob->FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart;
            nfi.SequenceNumber = pnfrh->SequenceNumber;

            pb += pnfrh->AttributesOffset;

            BOOL bSysFile = FALSE;

            for( ; ; ) 
            {
                union {
                    NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE* pnfa;
                    NTFS_STANDARD_ATTRIBUTE* pnsa;
                };

                switch (pna->Type)
                {
                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::StopTag:
                    goto __end;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::FileName:

                    pnfa = (NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE*)RtlOffsetToPointer(pnra, pnra->ValueOffset);

                    switch (pnfa->NameType)
                    {
                    case NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE::systemName:
                    case NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE::systemName2:
                        bSysFile = TRUE;
                        SystemName = pnfa->FileName, SystemNameLength = pnfa->FileNameLength;
                        break;
                    case NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE::longName:
                        LongName = pnfa->FileName, LongNameLength = pnfa->FileNameLength;
                        break;
                    case NTFS_FILENAME_ATTRIBUTE::shortName:
                        ShortName = pnfa->FileName, ShortNameLength = pnfa->FileNameLength;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::StandardInformation:

                    pnsa = (NTFS_STANDARD_ATTRIBUTE*)RtlOffsetToPointer(pnra, pnra->ValueOffset);
                    FileAttributes = pnsa->FileAttributes;
                    break;

                case NTFS_ATTRIBUTE::Data:
                    FileSize += pna->Nonresident ? pnaa->DataSize : pnra->ValueLength;
                    break;
                }

                pb += pna->Length;
            }

__end:;

            if (bSysFile)
            {
                HANDLE hFile;
                IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

                NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS,
                    FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT| FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID | FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    NtClose(hFile);
                }

                char sz[32];
                StrFormatByteSize64A(FileSize, sz, RTL_NUMBER_OF(sz));
                DbgPrint("%I64u: %08x %s [%x] %.*S\n", pnfrob->FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart, 
                    FileAttributes, sz, status, SystemNameLength, SystemName);
            }


        } while (0 <= (nfrib.FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart = pnfrob->FileReferenceNumber.QuadPart - 1));

    }

    CloseHandle(hVolume);

    return err;
}
```

with it i got next result:

```
38: 10000006 0 bytes [0] $Deleted
34: 00000020 10.0 MB [0] $TxfLogContainer00000000000000000002
33: 00000020 10.0 MB [0] $TxfLogContainer00000000000000000001
32: 00000020 64.0 KB [0] $TxfLog.blf
31: 00000026 1.00 MB [0] $Tops
30: 80000006 0 bytes [0] $Txf
29: 00000006 0 bytes [0] $TxfLog
28: 00000026 27.0 MB [0] $Repair
27: 00000006 0 bytes [0] $RmMetadata
26: 20000026 0 bytes [c0000034] $Reparse
25: 20000026 0 bytes [c0000034] $ObjId
24: 20000026 0 bytes [c0000034] $Quota
11: 00000006 0 bytes [0] $Extend
10: 00000006 128 KB [0] $UpCase
9: 20000006 0 bytes [c0000034] $Secure
8: 00000006 237 GB [c0000022] $BadClus
7: 00000006 8.00 KB [c0000022] $Boot
6: 00000006 7.42 MB [c0000022] $Bitmap
5: 00000806 0 bytes [0] .
4: 00000006 2.50 KB [0] $AttrDef
3: 00000006 0 bytes [0] $Volume
2: 00000006 64.0 MB [c0000022] $LogFile
1: 00000006 4.00 KB [0] $MFTMirr
0: 00000006 212 MB [0] $MFT
```

Comment: The OP only needs metadata for a few system files. For completeness, it would be nice if you included the constant file numbers for $LogFile, $BadClus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use `DeviceIoControl` / `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD` to read the **$MFT** without elevation. With the help of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights), I have worked out the minimum settings. Note the last few paragraphs at the bottom of that page.

1. in **Group Policy** `gpedit.msc`, add the (non-elevated) user account you'll be running under to the following to the following policies:

   > `Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment/...`
   > **Perform Volume Maintenance tasks**     (definitely needed)
   >   `Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment/...`
   > **Back up files and directories**     (not sure if this is essential)
2. So far, I haven't needed the following, but make a note of it in case you need to come back to it:

   > `Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment/...`
   > **Restore files and directories**
3. Run `gpupdate.exe` from a Windows command prompt, or wait about 15 minutes for the group policy changes to take effect.
4. Those changes *allow* your user account to acquire the privileges. As a one-time step every time your app starts, you'll have to explicitly adjust your token. Here's a standalone version of the **Win32 API** `AdjustTokenPrivileges`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.ComponentModel;

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static class AdjPriv
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, out IntPtr phtok);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValueW(IntPtr host, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String name, out long pluid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, in TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

    const int
        SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED    /**/ = 0x00000002,
        TOKEN_QUERY             /**/ = 0x00000008,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES /**/ = 0x00000020,
        ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED  /**/ = 0x00000514;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    struct TokPriv1Luid
    {
        public int Count;
        public long Luid;
        public int Attr;
    };

    public static bool SetPrivilege(String szSe)
    {
        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, out IntPtr htok))
            goto _error;

        var tp = new TokPriv1Luid { Count = 1, Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED };

        if (!LookupPrivilegeValueW(IntPtr.Zero, szSe, out tp.Luid))
            goto _error;

        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, in tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
            goto _error;

        return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED;

    _error:
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
};
```

5. Give the current user account the **"SeManageVolumePrivilege"** privilege when the app starts up by calling the `AdjPriv.SetPrivilege` utility function shown above. Call it once for each additional privilege you may also want to add.

```
static MyProgram()
{
    if (!AdjPriv.SetPrivilege("SeManageVolumePrivilege"))
        throw new SecurityException();

    /// etc...
}
```

6. And now for the code. I won't go into detail with the **p/Invoke** since everyone has their own way of doing it. I'll just show the exact flags and constants values passed into the two critical two API calls in order to work without prompting for elevation.

```
IntPtr h = CreateFileW(@"\\?\Volume{c2655473-adc2-4fe3-99a0-77d5bb1b809f}\",
                       FILE_ACCESS_READ_CONTROL,   // 0x00020000
                       FILE_SHARE_ANY,             // 7
                       IntPtr.Zero,
                       CREATE_MODE_OPEN_EXISTING,  // 3
                       FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, // 0x02000000
                       IntPtr.Zero);
```

7. And then finally...

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a 48-bit MFT index 'frn', recover the current "sequence number" of the file, which
/// can be used as the upper 16-bits to complete a usable FILE_REFERENCE (NTFS FileId):
/// </summary>
var frn = (FILE_REFERENCE)0x_0000_000000000218;
                    //       ^^^^----- ???

// lookup proceeds downwards, so set the sought-after upper 16 bits to max. seq. value
frn.Seq = 0xFFFF;

if (!DeviceIoControl(h, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD, in frn, out FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER rec) ||
    frn.Index != rec.file_ref.Index)
    throw new Win32Exception();

frn.Seq = rec.frh.SequenceNumber;
                                          //    vvvv--- !!!
Console.WriteLine($"0x{frn:X16}");        // 0x_0092_000000000218
```

**Notes:**

It works! Well at least for me on **Windows 10**, Version *10.0.18362.387*. Please notice the backslash `...\` at the end of the **Volume Guid path** in `CreateFileW`. The code will not work without it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer. But I think manipulating user _privileges_ doesn't exactly qualify as unprivileged. Because one is literally assigning the privilege. And at least `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE` (which you say is not needed) _and_ `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE` (which you say is needed) are anything but harmless w.r.t. security. The latter literally allows you to write data _below_ the file system layer and the former allows to replace (even admin-owned) files _at_ the file system layer. Still +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yeah, sorry i conflated “unprivileged” with “not-elevated” reading your question, but then went ahead and made the distinction in my answer. Hope it’s useful to someone anyway.